# Synchronize data from JavaME mobile locally

Tags: synchronization, java-me, midp

I would like to write a litte data-entry app for mobile phones using JavaME (MIDP/CLDC). How do I best synchronize the data with a local application on my PC (resp. just transfer the data to the PC)? Is there any standard way to connect to the PC if the mobile is plugged in via an USB cable?

I know that I could just connect to some Web service but I'd like rather not to use the device's internet connection.

The app should work on as many devices as possible (of course), but a hint for some specific devices would be appreciated too...

Sorry if the question is a bit general but I'm new to JavaME programming and I didn't find any good resources about this topic on the web ...

Answer (score 2):

Nokia Series60 devices should have a javax.microedition.io.CommConnection that would allow the use of USB, InfraRed and/or Bluetooth comm ports via the generic GCF API.

If you want soemthing that works on most Bluetooth-enabled phones, JSR-82 can be used for data transfer. the specification for that is at http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=82

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to save the data in a pre-determined location using the file connection API. The synchronization work would then be done entirely by the PC application which scans for the presence of a particular folder on the device. If found it could write new data into the folder, or read changed data from it, both activities being picked up by the J2ME app the next time it starts.